# How to detect which Identity Provider used for login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We utilize AWS Cognito to perform all authentication in our product. Users can try to login using one of the `Facebook, Google, Amazon, Microsoft` accounts. So we need to identify the `user` who tried to log in using which `Identity Provider` or bearer token utilized. So we will store those pieces of information. Is there any way that we can get provider Infos something like its `suffix`, and so on?

It will be stored as I mentioned below.

```
 AuthByEmail :1,
 ByMobile: 0,
 AWSIPName: Google,
 AWSClientName:client101,
 Suffix: Google_client101_jhon@client101.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the request was made with temporary security credentials obtained by web identity federation, you can find an element called `webIdFederationData` that lists information about the identity provider in the respective CloudTrail events’ `userIdentity`. Attributes for this element are:

- `federatedProvider` – The principal name of the identity provider (for example, `www.amazon.com` for Login with Amazon or `accounts.google.com` for Google).
- `attributes` – The application ID and user ID as reported by the provider (for example, `www.amazon.com:app_id` and `www.amazon.com:user_id` for Login with Amazon).

You can learn more about the structure and content of the [CloudTrail userIdentity in different cases here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-user-identity.html).

Comment: Is it possible to get pieces of information like ProviderName, ClientName, and so on from the successful login operation? CloudTrail will log into S3 and we will need to do some additional operation to fetch data. It would be much faster if we will configure or do something to get Provider information from success login.

Comment: You don’t have to wait for the Event to be logged to S3.  You can use an Amazon EventBridge Rule to process the API call as it happens. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/create-eventbridge-cloudtrail-rule.html